# File upload into database is empty

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I want to upload an array of files, send it to javascript formData object and then via ajax to some php script which will put the file into database. It works fine when I upload one file, send it to formData object in javascript and send it to php.

Problem is when I send an array of files via formData object, my php script will insert an empty file into database (`BLOB - 0B`). What do I do wrong?

Example:

```
   <form method="post" action="javascript:sendPHP()" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <input type="file" onchange = 'handleFiles(this.files)' name="pics[]" />
   <input type="file" onchange = 'handleFiles(this.files)' name="pics[]" />
   <input type="file" onchange = 'handleFiles(this.files)' name="pics[]" />
   <input type="submit" value="Upload" />

   //Javascript
   var formData = new FormData(); 

   function handleFiles(files) {
   var file = files[0];
   formData.append('pics[]', file, file.name);
   }

  function sendPHP() {
     $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "../php/haus.php",
            data: formData,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success: function(data){}
        })}


    //php 
    if(strtolower($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) == 'post' && !empty($_FILES))
 {
    foreach($_FILES['pics']['tmp_name'] as $index => $tmpName )
   {

    if(!empty($tmpName) && is_uploaded_file($tmpName))
     {

           $imgData=  addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['pics']['tmp_name']));
         $resultPics = $dbConnection->query("INSERT INTO picture (pic, text, id) VALUES ('".$imgData."', 'Hi','1')");

 }
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

- You are missing this attribute `multiple="multiple"` in your `<input>` 
  Do it this way ,

`<input type="file" onchange = 'handleFiles(this.files)' name="pics[]" multiple="multiple" />`

- This function handles only single file upload

  `function handleFiles(files) {
     var file = files[0];
     formData.append('pics[]', file, file.name);
     }`

For multiple uploads you need to use a loop inside to append to each file.

Something Like this ,

`function handleFiles(files) {
        for(var file in files)
       {
          formData.append('pics[]', file, file.name);
       }`

- The `PHP` part , you need to use a loop there as well to loop through each file and use `json_encode()` to convert the array of files into json string , so that you can insert the record as a string in the database and use `json_decode()` when retrieving the data back from DB.

Hope this helps.